# PyInstaller giving error when using Langdetect

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am working on a project which involves doing a language check for an input. When we try to turn it into a .exe file using [PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/), it gives away this errors:

```
C:\Users\luismanj\Allegations_TEF_ARG\dist>.\allegations.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "allegations.py", line 16, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "C:\Users\luismanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "language_check.py", line 1, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "C:\Users\luismanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "langdetect\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "C:\Users\luismanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "langdetect\detector_factory.py", line 10, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "C:\Users\luismanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "langdetect\detector.py", line 9, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "C:\Users\luismanj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "langdetect\utils\ngram.py", line 23, in <module>
File "langdetect\utils\ngram.py", line 24, in NGram
File "langdetect\utils\messages.py", line 22, in get_string
File "langdetect\utils\messages.py", line 9, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\luismanj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI118322\\langdetect\\utils\\messages.properties'
[22436] Failed to execute script allegations
```

It seems the main problem as of now is the library [Langdetect](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/), which we have been using without issues until now. If anyone knows the cause or has found a workaround for this problem, any comment will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: just go to the path:
'C:\\Users\\luismanj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI118322\\langdetect\\utils\\messages.properties'

Copy the langdetect folder, and then past it in the same directory of your .exe generated by pyinstaller

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, DID YOU FIND SOMETHING ?